# How can I create multiple Google Maps with driving directions on the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3

Thanks for any help you can provide! I have a webpage that is supposed to display multiple Google maps with driving directions and routes. However, I can only get one of the maps to load, and this map does not show the driving directions. I'm using Ruby on Rails to create the page.

**Edit 3 Based on Carl's Comments**

The start and end addresses appear correctly with my "@newmaps.each do" at the bottom. However, I was getting JS errors from the this.directionsDisplay and from this.directionsService so I moved both into a function initialize(). Still getting errors in the DirectionHelper.prototype.calcRoute

The error is, "ReferenceError: google is not defined" 
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    function DirectionHelper(id)
{
  var rendererOptions, chicago, mapOptions;
  this.directionsDisplay = null;
  this.id = id;
  this.map = null;


  rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true,
    panel:     document.getElementById('directions_panel' + this.id)
  };

  function initialize() {
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

  mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"+this.id), mapOptions);

  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(this.map));
}
}
    DirectionHelper.prototype.calcRoute = function(start, end, waypoints){
      var request, 
          self = this;
      var request = {
          origin: start, // an address or LatLng
          destination: end, // an address or a LatLng
          optimizeWaypoints: optimize,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };

      this.directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        var theRoute, summaryPanel;
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          self.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

          theRoute = response.routes[0];
          summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel" + self.id);

          summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
          // For each route, display summary information.
          for (var i = 0; i < theRoute.legs.length; i++) {
            var routeSegment = i+1;
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += theRoute.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += theRoute.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += theRoute.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += theRoute.legs[i].duration.text + "<br /><br />";
          }
        }

        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
         alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
        }
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED){
          alert("Error: You have included more than eight stops along the way. Please use only eight or fewer stops, and try again.");
        }
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.INVALID_REQUEST){
          alert("Error: You may be missing a starting or ending point, or you may have included two starting points or two ending points: one in the dropdown menu and one in the entry box. Please edit your map and try again.");
        }
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND){
          alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
        }
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
         alert("We're sorry! This is an internal error with Go See Campus. Please contact us so we can resolve it.");
        }
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR){
         alert("Error: Something went wrong when you loaded this page. Try loading the page again. You may need to log out, clear your temporary files, and log back in.");
        }
      });
    };

      var dirHelper = null;
      <% @newmaps.each do |newsavedmap| %>
      dirHelper = new DirectionHelper(<%= newsavedmap.id %>);
      <%= "dirHelper.calcRoute('#{newsavedmap.start}', '#{newsavedmap.end}');" %>
      <% end %>
    </script>
```

**EARLIER VERSIONS**

**Javascript**

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    <% for newsavedmap in @newmaps %>

    $(function(){

        var directionsDisplay<%= newsavedmap.id %>;
        var map<%= newsavedmap.id %>;           

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(map<%= newsavedmap.id %>));
    });

        var directionsService<%= newsavedmap.id %> = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


    function initialize() {
          var rendererOptions<%= newsavedmap.id %> = {
          draggable: true,
          panel:document.getElementById('directions_panel<%= newsavedmap.id %>')
         };

          directionsDisplay<%= newsavedmap.id %> = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions<%= newsavedmap.id %>);
          var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
              var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 6,
              center: chicago,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
          map<%= newsavedmap.id %> = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas<%= newsavedmap.id %>"), mapOptions);

          directionsDisplay<%= newsavedmap.id %>.setMap(map<%= newsavedmap.id %>);
        }

        function calcRoute() {

          var request<%= newsavedmap.id %> = {
              origin: '<%= newsavedmap.start %>',
              destination: '<%= newsavedmap.end %>',
              waypoints: '<%= newsavedmap.waypoints %>',
              optimizeWaypoints: optimize,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService<%= newsavedmap.id %>.route<%= newsavedmap.id %>(request<%= newsavedmap.id %>, function(response<%= newsavedmap.id %>, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay<%= newsavedmap.id %>.setDirections(response<%= newsavedmap.id %>);
              var route<%= newsavedmap.id %> = response<%= newsavedmap.id %>.routes[0];
              var summaryPanel<%= newsavedmap.id %> = document.getElementById("directions_panel<%= newsavedmap.id %>");

              summaryPanel<%= newsavedmap.id %>.innerHTML = "";
              // For each route, display summary information.
              for (var i = 0; i < route<%= newsavedmap.id %>.legs.length; i++) {
                var routeSegment = i+1;
                summaryPanel<%= newsavedmap.id %>.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
                summaryPanel<%= newsavedmap.id %>.innerHTML += route<%= newsavedmap.id %>.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                summaryPanel<%= newsavedmap.id %>.innerHTML += route<%= newsavedmap.id %>.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                summaryPanel<%= newsavedmap.id %>.innerHTML += route<%= newsavedmap.id %>.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
                summaryPanel<%= newsavedmap.id %>.innerHTML += route<%= newsavedmap.id %>.legs[i].duration.text + "<br /><br />";
              }
            }

                if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                 alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
                 }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED){
               alert("Error: You have included more than eight stops along the way. Please use only eight or fewer stops, and try again.");
                }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.INVALID_REQUEST){
                alert("Error: You may be missing a starting or ending point, or you may have included two starting points or two ending points: one in the dropdown menu and one in the entry box. Please edit your map and try again.");
               }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND){
                alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
                 }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
                 alert("We're sorry! This is an internal error with Go See Campus. Please contact us so we can resolve it.");
                 }
                 if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR){
                 alert("Error: Something went wrong when you loaded this page. Try loading the page again. You may need to log out, clear your temporary files, and log back in.");
                  }


          });
        }; 
        <% end if @newmaps %>
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <% for newsavedmap in @newmaps %>

    <div class="wholemap">
        <% if newsavedmap.name != nil and newsavedmap.name != '' %>
        <h4><%= newsavedmap.name %></h4>
        <% else %>
        <h4>Untitled Map</h4>
        <% end %>
        <a class="directions" href="#">Show Driving Directions</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="map" id="map_canvas<%= newsavedmap.id %>"></div>
    <div class="route" id="directions_panel<%= newsavedmap.id %>"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <a id="print<%= newsavedmap.id %>" target="_blank" class="printmap">Print this map</a>
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Sample JS results**

```
    $(function(){
        var directionsDisplay6;
        var map6;           
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(map6));
    });

        var directionsService6 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();           

    function initialize() {
          var rendererOptions6 = {
          draggable: true,
          panel:document.getElementById('directions_panel6')
         };

          directionsDisplay6 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions6);
          var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
              var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 6,
              center: chicago,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
          map6 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas6"), mapOptions);

          directionsDisplay6.setMap(map6);
        }

        function calcRoute() {

          var request6 = {
              origin: '2750 Pleasant Hill Rd Duluth, GA 30096',
              destination: '500 Lee Drive, Baton Rouge, Louisiana 70808',
              waypoints: '737 Denham Progress Rd Buckatunna, MS 39322',
              optimizeWaypoints: optimize,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService6.route6(request6, function(response6, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay6.setDirections(response6);
              var route6 = response6.routes[0];
              var summaryPanel6 = document.getElementById("directions_panel6");

              summaryPanel6.innerHTML = "";
              // For each route, display summary information.
              for (var i = 0; i < route6.legs.length; i++) {
                var routeSegment = i+1;
                summaryPanel6.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
                summaryPanel6.innerHTML += route6.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                summaryPanel6.innerHTML += route6.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                summaryPanel6.innerHTML += route6.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
                summaryPanel6.innerHTML += route6.legs[i].duration.text + "<br /><br />";
              }
            }

                if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                 alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
                 }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED){
               alert("Error: You have included more than eight stops along the way. Please use only eight or fewer stops, and try again.");
                }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.INVALID_REQUEST){
                alert("Error: You may be missing a starting or ending point, or you may have included two starting points or two ending points: one in the dropdown menu and one in the entry box. Please edit your map and try again.");
               }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND){
                alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
                 }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
                 alert("We're sorry! This is an internal error with Go See Campus. Please contact us so we can resolve it.");
                 }
                 if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR){
                 alert("Error: Something went wrong when you loaded this page. Try loading the page again. You may need to log out, clear your temporary files, and log back in.");
                  }


          });
        }; 


    $(function(){

        var directionsDisplay7;
        var map7;           

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(map7));
    });

        var directionsService7 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


    function initialize() {
          var rendererOptions7 = {
          draggable: true,
          panel:document.getElementById('directions_panel7')
         };

          directionsDisplay7 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions7);
          var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
              var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 6,
              center: chicago,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
          map7 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas7"), mapOptions);

          directionsDisplay7.setMap(map7);
        }

        function calcRoute() {

          var request7 = {
              origin: '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC 20500',
              destination: '103 Federal St Pittsburgh, PA 15212',
              waypoints: '50 Summit Ave Hagerstown, MD 21740',
              optimizeWaypoints: optimize,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService7.route7(request7, function(response7, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay7.setDirections(response7);
              var route7 = response7.routes[0];
              var summaryPanel7 = document.getElementById("directions_panel7");

              summaryPanel7.innerHTML = "";
              // For each route, display summary information.
              for (var i = 0; i < route7.legs.length; i++) {
                var routeSegment = i+1;
                summaryPanel7.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
                summaryPanel7.innerHTML += route7.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                summaryPanel7.innerHTML += route7.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                summaryPanel7.innerHTML += route7.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
                summaryPanel7.innerHTML += route7.legs[i].duration.text + "<br /><br />";
              }
            }

                if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                 alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
                 }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED){
               alert("Error: You have included more than eight stops along the way. Please use only eight or fewer stops, and try again.");
                }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.INVALID_REQUEST){
                alert("Error: You may be missing a starting or ending point, or you may have included two starting points or two ending points: one in the dropdown menu and one in the entry box. Please edit your map and try again.");
               }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND){
                alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
                 }
               if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
                 alert("We're sorry! This is an internal error with Go See Campus. Please contact us so we can resolve it.");
                 }
                 if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR){
                 alert("Error: Something went wrong when you loaded this page. Try loading the page again. You may need to log out, clear your temporary files, and log back in.");
                  }


          });
        };
```

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to Carl for the attempt. The immediate solution didn't work, but maybe tweaking will help. The first thing I did was alter the Ruby code to fit my setup:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">       
      var dirHelper = null;
      <% @newmaps.each do |newsavedmap| %>
        dirHelper = new DirectionHelper(newsavedmap.id);
        dirHelper.calcRoute(newsavedmap.start, newsavedmap.end, newsavedmap.waypoints);
      <% end %>
    </script>
```

My immediate error in the console: DirectionHelper is not defined. I solved this by combining the Ruby javascript above with the Javascript for Google Maps.

Next error: newsavedmap is not defined. I tried solving this by replacing newsavedmap with <%= newsavedmap.WHATEVER %> and enclosing start, end, and waypoints within quotes. However, this just resulted in another error (a is null: somehow related to my Google Ads javascript, which should work just fine.) What should I do next? Is there a different approach I should take?

**Edit 2**

I've tried Carl's latest solution (thanks!) but ran into more errors. Here's my setup: I used his function DirectionHelper code and everything else in the top block exactly as-is. Then, in a separate  tag specific to my "newmaps" view, I used the bottom Ruby code. It looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dirHelper = null;
      <% @newmaps.each do |newsavedmap| %>
        dirHelper = new DirectionHelper(newsavedmap.id);
    <%= "dirHelper.calcRoute('#{newsavedmap.start}', '#{newsavedmap.end}', '#{'5 Main Street Charlestown MA'}');" %>
    <% end %>
    </script>
```

Notice that I used a constant for my waypoints since they were giving me a bunch of errors, which I wanted to separate from the javascript problems.

Now, I'm just giving a javascript error: newsavedmap is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: You may have some js scoping issues since your function names are overwriting themselves in your main for loop. You may want to move some of those functions to objects and as you iterate over the rails models, you create a new js-map object, and pass it the params it needs to create the map, etc. That may not solve all your issues, but I think it will get you in the right direction.

Comment: newsavedmap is a ruby object, not a js one. You need to escape newsavedmap.id with erb, <%= newsavedmap.id %>

Comment: Thanks, Carl. Are you referring to my Edit 3 version at the top? I think I use erb there with newsavedmap.id .

Comment: Nope, I was looking at the example at the bottom :-/ What is the error? You ask how to get it working, but what is the problem now?

Comment: Carl, I've updated the code (Edit 3 above) to reflect the most recent bug. Getting there.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with full-code (all js/html/css, no ruby, you'll have to replace that on your own).

Comment: Thanks, Carl. Still unable to get it going. I took the code you provided, cut out everything between `var startElement` and `document.body.appendChild(directionsPanelElement);` , replaced the bottom `function initialize() {var dirHelper = null;` with my Ruby code from Edit 3, and then changed your `"map_"+this.id` to `"mapcanvas_"+this.id`. Still an error: google is not defined: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); When I cut this line, the maps don't load either.

Comment: Are you not including google maps on the page? For google stuff, follow these guides (seems like you copied some of their examples already): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: See how I included google in my HTML example? Do that.

Comment: My Ruby controller is creating a separate map canvas and panel for each. Looks like `<div class="map" id="map_canvas<%= newsavedmap.id %>" style="width: 620px; height: 400px;margin-bottom: 15px;">` and `<div id="directions_panel<%= newsavedmap.id %>"></div>`. Is that what you mean? I also have the script tag pointing to the Google Maps API.

Comment: If "google" is undefined, then you have not properly included google maps. Or, you are trying to reference "google" in your scripts before google maps has loaded. Make sure google script is loaded BEFORE you run any of your other javascript.

Answer (score 0):

2013.08.15 Alright, updating my answer with a full-example of all js, html, css. You can fill in the ruby yourself, which will be trivial.

[Code is also on github, here.](https://github.com/cfurrow/stackoverflow-multi-googledir)

HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>multi directions</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.map{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.directions{
  width:500px;
  border: dashed 1px #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
function DirectionHelper(id)
{
  var rendererOptions, chicago, mapOptions;
  this.directionsDisplay = null;
  this.id = id;
  this.map = null;
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  var startElement = document.createElement('input');
  startElement.id = 'start_'+id;
  startElement.value = 'The Loop';
  document.body.appendChild(startElement);
  var endElement = document.createElement('input');
  endElement.id = 'end_'+id;
  endElement.value = 'Grant Park';
  document.body.appendChild(endElement);
  var mapElement = document.createElement('div');
  mapElement.id = "map_" + id;
  mapElement.className = 'map';
  document.body.appendChild(mapElement);
  var directionsPanelElement = document.createElement('div');
  directionsPanelElement.id = 'directions_panel'+id;
  directionsPanelElement.className='directions';
  document.body.appendChild(directionsPanelElement);

  rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true,
    panel:     document.getElementById('directions_panel' + this.id)
  };
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

  chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

  mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_"+this.id), mapOptions);
  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);
}
DirectionHelper.prototype.calcRoute = function(start, end, waypoints){
  var request, 
      self = this;
  request = {
    origin: start, // an address or LatLng
    destination: end, // an address or a LatLng
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  console.log(request)
  this.directionsService.route(request,function(r,s){ console.log('shit') })
  this.directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    var theRoute, summaryPanel;
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      self.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

      theRoute = response.routes[0];
      summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel" + self.id);

      summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < theRoute.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i+1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += theRoute.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += theRoute.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += theRoute.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += theRoute.legs[i].duration.text + "<br /><br />";
      }
    }

    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
      alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
    }
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED){
      alert("Error: You have included more than eight stops along the way. Please use only eight or fewer stops, and try again.");
    }
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.INVALID_REQUEST){
      alert("Error: You may be missing a starting or ending point, or you may have included two starting points or two ending points: one in the dropdown menu and one in the entry box. Please edit your map and try again.");
    }
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND){
      alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found. If you think this is an error with our website, please contact us.");
    }
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
      alert("We're sorry! This is an internal error with Go See Campus. Please contact us so we can resolve it.");
    }
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR){
      alert("Error: Something went wrong when you loaded this page. Try loading the page again. You may need to log out, clear your temporary files, and log back in.");
    }
  });
};

function initialize() {  
  var dirHelper = null;
  for(var i=1; i<6; i++){
    dirHelper = new DirectionHelper(i);
    dirHelper.calcRoute(document.getElementById('start_'+i).value, document.getElementById('end_'+i).value);

  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Hi, Carl! I've updated my code with the response. Appreciate any other help you can offer!

Comment: Sorry, it was part real code, part pseudo code to get you going. You'll need to pass whatever map.start is to javascript, and that will probably mean deserializing it from ruby to javascript. You can try to output a string of the results to your calcRoute() method via something like <%= "dirHelper.calcRoute(#{map.start}, #{map.end}, #{map.waypoints})". If map.start is supposed to be a google LatLng object, then build it as a string and pass it in. Same goes for map.end, and map.waypoints. If waypoints should be an array of points, serialize it as a json array.

Comment: I've updated the lower code-block to help you out. Just make modifications to that if need-be, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have created a third edit that includes the two sections of code in the same javascript along with my Ruby code. The start and end addresses appear correctly and JS throws no errors, but the maps still won't provide directions. Thanks for any help you can offer!